# Download images uploaded in backend with Sprout Form Plugin

Tags: plugin-sproutforms

I'm using sprouts form for craft and I built a form with a file upload field. It works fine but the problem is that in the backend form entries, I can only see the uploaded image as a thumbnail (img attached).

Is there anyway to download the image from the backend? or at list get the link to open it with the browser in full size?

[image: Image uploaded in backend]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a plugin that will add Download (well, open in new tab) links to files in the Assets fields when editing entries.

[AssetLinks](https://github.com/Hambrook/AssetLinks)

Comment: Nice answer Rick! I like that the time of the Initial Commit in the repo falls squarely between the time of our two replies.

Comment: Thanks Ben, it's my first Craft plugin (albeit a very modest one).

I would've liked to do it via the double-click menu but it didn't appear to be pluggable.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, is the current answer, but unfortunately it's not obvious or easy yet.

The problem, in my view, is actually the behavior allowed with the Craft Assets field, but the workflow where an admin user arrives at an asset field that was submitted by a user and that they wish to download is more likely to be encountered in a Form workflow.

I have talked through the issue for a workflow like this with Pixel & Tonic and it's on their radar, but can't speak to how or when it might be addressed.

---

Right now, if you want do download that image you have to:

1. Note down the name of the image
2. Go to the Assets tab and find the image where it was uploaded
3. Select the checkbox next to the image
4. Select "View Image" from the dropdown (http://cl.ly/image/0U3o2e3X122R)
5. Download the image from your browser

It's as painful for me to write those steps as it is for you to read them!

Some alternatives to consider,

**Use Sprout Email to send links**

You could consider using custom emails with Sprout Email, and having your templates output the full URL to the assets you want to allow to be downloaded.

**Attach the files to your emails using Sprout Forms**

You can add a hidden config setting to your `craft/config/general.php` which enables the default Sprout Forms Notifications to add file attachments to the notification emails, and just download the files from the email notifications.

```
'sproutForms' => array(
    'enableFileAttachments' => true,
),
```

---

In the long run, I hope my answer becomes dated and you will see:

1. Assets Field allows users to right click and view or download images directly (Pixel & Tonic, I can't make any claims here)
2. Sprout Email Notifications allow file attachments (Barrel Strength Design, it's on our list)
3. Sprout Forms moves the option for file attachments into the Control Panel and out of a hidden config (Barrel Strength Design, it's on our list)

Comment: How would outputting links from an email template look?  What are the properties on the field that I should be looking for?

Comment: If the Event being triggered provides related data to Sprout Email that data  will be available using the `object` variable. So you can access your asset URL with `{{ object.assetFieldHandle.first().getUrl() }}`.